# Getting "The provided API key is expired." error on using Places API

Tags: android, api, google-places-api

I have generated Server key from Google console for Places API key.
But whenever i am hitting the service i am getting " The provided API key is expired " error.

I have tried regenerating the key but still got same error.

Answer (score 150):

I have faced same issue... But finally got resolved. **Google place services will take 10 minutes to make the services available for new API KEY created.** Services will start working after 10 minutes, till then we get error as "The provided API key is expired."

Comment: Thanks, You just saved me from pulling my hair out. :/

Comment: This expiration is for debug builds right? otherwise, how would it be possible to update keys in app after it is released on the Play Store?

Comment: @Talha, This is only for new API KEY created.

Comment: No I mean the expiration? The error when you get that key is expired generate new key, then how my released app is supposed to know? I guess release builds will have permanent keys?

Comment: Thanks, Google, another reason to have that coffee.

Comment: 10 mins! I am taking a break.

Comment: Why they can't simply mention that in documentation or after key creation... Uhhh

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure, your key is present in google play console or not**. I had the same problem but when I checked my key on google place it was not there. It might be deleted by me by mistake or Google had deleted that key due to some reason.  But by creating new key and I checked after 10 minute it is working.

Answer (score 1):

After 48 hours of regenerating my Google Maps API key I was receiving this error.

It turned out I had not restarted my React application for over >48 hours in my local environment. Updating my .env file did nothing to update the key with a browser refresh, the app process had to be stopped and restarted in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You have to activate the access in services in Google console by going to *APIs* then activate *Places API*

Comment: Even if it is enabled, we are getting The provided API key is expired message

Answer (score 0):

> ExpiredKeyMapError    Error

The API key included in the script element that loads the API has expired or is not recognized by the system. You may receive this error after creating a new API key if you try to use the key before it is recognized by the system. Wait a few minutes and try again, or you may need to generate a new API key in the Google Cloud Platform Console.