# OVER_QUERY_LIMIT using google places

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, google-places-api

I'm trying to use the google api for auto-complete.
I created a key and did some testing, due to an error in my code, that sent many requests in a short time I had the error: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

I made the correction of my code, deleted the used key and created a new one. Now I get the following message:

```
{
   "error_message" : "The provided API key is expired.",
   "predictions" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Google place services will take 10 minutes to make the services available for new API KEY created. Services will start working after 10 minutes. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788069/getting-the-provided-api-key-is-expired-error-on-using-places-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clarity of the message is quite obvious.
The problem is that google warns you that you have a 100k limit available.
The detail is in: these 100k is only available when billing is activated, without activating billing the limit drops to 1.
I would never imagine that.
But it's settled!

The tip is for anyone to go through the same problem

Answer (score 0):

The Message you are getting seems to be very clear.
You could have a licence an this license seems to be exceeded.
Please read the documentation.